# How to find a list of steps needed to reorder a list to get another list?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, list, reorderlist

Let's assume we have to lists (Expressed as arrays or whatever in any language). These lists are equally long and contain the same unique elements - but in a different order.

For example:

```
First list: A, B, C, D
Second list: A, D, B, C
```

Now what I'm trying to find is a list of steps that is needed to reorder the first list to match the second list. In this example, there would only be one step:

```
3 -> 1
```

That is, because the element at index 3 was moved to index 1. Note that B and C do change indexes, but that is only because they are "making space" for D when it is inserted at index 1, so this step should not be included in the list of moves!

Another example:

```
First list: A, B, C, D, E, F
Second list: D, B, A, C, E, F
Changes:  3 -> 0, 1 -> 1
```

Because D was moved to index 0 and B was moved to 1. Note that for B, we use the original index 1 instead of what it would have been after the first move was performed.

These steps are all "performed at once" - meaning there is no order, but we just create a new list by putting the moved elements to where they should be and then filling the remaining slots with the remaining elements.

Now my question is: Does anybody know any algorithm to do this?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Do you need to find a shortest list of steps or any suitable list is acceptable?

Comment: @Alexei Shestakov: any suitable list is acceptable! :-)

Comment: can't you just move all of the elements to their respective positions then? So for your second example the moves would be: 5 -> 5, 4-> 4, 3 -> 0, 2 -> 3, 1 -> 1, 0 -> 2?

Comment: I didn't think about it that way... Well, i guess i do need the shortest list. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the shortest list of steps, perform a [Longest Increasing Subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) on the list and change only the position of the elements outside that subsequence.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the shortest list of steps and the trivial solution is not acceptable for some reason then here is my solution in python. I think that it is simple enough to understand:

```
first = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
second = ['A', 'D', 'B', 'C']
steps = []
tmp = second[:]  # copy second list to temp list
for pos in range(len(first)):
    # find position where first and temp lists are different
    if first[pos] != tmp[pos]:
        # get element that should be placed in position 'pos'
        element = first[pos]
        # get position of that element in second list
        sec_pos = second.index(element)
        # add step: move element from sec_pos to pos
        step = '%d -> %d' % (sec_pos, pos)
        steps.append(step)
        # do permutation in temp list
        tmp.remove(element)  # remove element
        tmp.insert(pos, element)  # put it in proper position
        # print step and intermediate result
        print step, tmp
print steps
```

Output:

> 2 -> 1 ['A', 'B', 'D', 'C']
>
> 3 -> 2 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
>
> ['2 -> 1', '3 -> 2']